# Need help with multiple WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have an UPDATE query I'd like to perform.

But there need to be 2 conditions met before we can update a quantity in the database.

First, the sessions_id() must match one of the sessionid's in the sessionid column, and second, the Description of the product must match the description of the product corresponding to the sessionid.

Here's what I have:

```
mysql_query(UPDATE cart 
               SET quantity = $q, 
             WHERE sessionid = "'.session_id().'" 
               AND description = $d') or die(mysql_error());
```

Now, it is giving me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE sessionid="bqlbh5rdogbhmq70skhtkbvmb0" AND description=$d' at line 1

However, I have copied this update query straight from W3Schools, so it must be correct, right? Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: why would you trust w3schools over MySQL documentation?

Comment: **The first and most important thing you ought to understand:** this is NOT update query. This is PHP code. You have to learn to distinguish PHP code from SQL code, or you won't move any further.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel dude seriously... go away, 95% of the code posted is in fact a SQL query. BFD if its called from in PHP. You're such a troll, it amazes me that you have any rep at all.

Comment: @Col. I never said I was any good at PHP or SQL. Yes, I understand the difference. It is php code that SHOULD be performing an update. No need to be a dick about it.

Comment: Nope, you don't. In fact, you have syntax errors in both PHP and SQL. And you have to separate it to solve. Your first concern should be proper SQL. only after you get it, you can move to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look that way:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET quantity = $q WHERE sessionid='" .session_id(). "' AND description = '$d'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Sorry singles, this also gives me an error: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE sessionid='bqlbh5rdogbhmq70skhtkbvmb0' AND description = ''' at line 1**

Comment: So that mean that `$d` variable is empty.

Comment: Yeah, it does. But then I do a print_f() on it, and it prints contents of $d to the page, so it isn't really empty. It doesn't make sense to me. How could mysql think it's empty, when php can still print it to the page?

Comment: Please dump your `$d` with `var_dump($d)` and show the output.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure what just happened. But I just refreshed the page, and now it has worked twice. Strange, but cool :) Thanks heaps singles! :D

Comment: @Lucifer Mysql never thinks of PHP variables, baby :) That's what I am talking about. you cannot distinguish SQL from PHP but too self-conceited to admit and learn.

Comment: Wow. It worked! ... and here goes another 2-hour mess when someone tell him of sql injections...

Comment: @Lucifer in a separate file? MWAHAHAHAHAHAH!

Comment: Yes, lol. When I'm learning something new (like updating with php + mysql), I start with the bare basics, then once I've got that right I then worry about sql injections and parameterized queries. I keep the sanitization script in a separate file just because it makes the page look ugly and bulky. It's really long.

Comment: @Lucifer one cannot make sanitization in the separate file. all sanitization belongs to the query and nothing else. If not - you are vulnerable

Comment: Really? I was tought to separate it from everything else. Looks like I've got some more reading to do. :S

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because of the ',' sign before the WHERE statement. The correct query would be:

`mysql_query( "UPDATE cart SET quantity = " . $q . " WHERE sessionid = "' . session_id( ) . '" AND description = " . $d . "" ) or die( mysql_error( ) );`

Comment: I took that away, now it says this: **Unknown column '$d' in 'where clause'** --- Eh!? Why are PHP errors so cryptic?

Comment: @Lucifer your original query is also missing a single quote... you wrote it as `$d'` it should be `'$d'` or no quotes at all

Comment: that is not a php error, and it is because you dont escape the fields so mysql has to guess what is what

Comment: Sorry Martijn, that query gives me this error: **
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in E:\web\onestopf\edit.php on line 23
**

Comment: no that is a php error, not the query... missing a ' somewhere

Answer (score 1):

remove the `,` (comma) after `$q`

Answer (score 1):

the code you have pasted is badly formatted, and i doubt the code used in your app.

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "UPDATE `cart` SET `quantity` = '%d' WHERE `sessionid` = '%s' AND `description` = '%s'", 
    $q, 
    session_id(), 
    $d
);
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: +1 for nice formatting. This prevents lots of errors :)
But your code still have the error with the comma before WHERE

Comment: @Radoslav Georgiev but it lacks error handling and doesn't fit to the screen.

Comment: Col. the question is not about error handling, its about fixing errors which are much easier to do when code is formatted properly. baby steps...

Comment: Sorry dogmatic69, that doesn't have any effect at all. Doesn't update. No warnings or errors either.

Comment: well maybe there is no sessionid that is matching your update query. And any how, why are you updating with description as a constraint... you should have a pk of id or something similar to update against.

Comment: There is. I've triple checked everything before I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have problem with the single quotes here `.'" AND description=$d')` and $d is not parsed. This will result wrong SQL query.
Change the single quotes to double quotes or just use string append `.` to append the value of `$d`, not the literal $d

example :

```
$a = 5;
$b = 'a is $a'; // a is $a;
$c = "a is $a"; // a is 5
```